# What is the difference between growth hormone and growth factor

Tags: endocrinology

What is the difference between growth factor and growth hormone?

I am aware of the fact that hormones are directly poured into the blood stream and that the growth factors can be released by non endocrine organs.

But how else do they vary from each other ?

And are they functionally different and if yes how?

Comment: Welcome to the site. What research have you done on your own to answer this question? The Biology.SE community has agreed that **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Our goal is not simply to be an answer site, but rather a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help along the way.

Comment: Plugging your exact question title into Google yields many helpful resources.